# Competitive Programming - Code gives different answers on online compilers

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I was trying to solve the [problem 811C on codeforces](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/811/C). I started off coding on sublime-text and managed to come up with a solution after some time. When I ran the program, it gave me the correct answer but when I submitted the code, for some reason I am getting a different answer on codeforces. I **checked if the array is going out of bounds**, but that doesn't seem to be the reason. Here's the code:

```
/* Code Readability Credit : Max Vollmer */
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

// terms[] stores the value of all the terms. leftMosts[i] and rightMosts[i] store the leftmost and rightmost occurrences of the ith element in terms[]. 
//solvedValues[] stands for dynamic programming and stores the pre calculated terms of the function solve()
int numberOfTerms;
int terms[5005];
int leftMosts[5005];
int rightMosts[5005];
int solvedValues[5005];

int comf(int left,int right)// comf = comfort (see problem statement if you do not understand this)
{ 
    std::set<int> track;
    int ret = 0;
    for(int i = left; i <= right; i++)
    {
        if (!track.count(terms[i]))
        {
            ret = (ret^terms[i]);
            track.insert(terms[i]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

// below, solve stands for 'solve', it is terms recursive memoized function
// returns max sequence from i to (numberOfTerms-1). to find max, call solve(0, -1) so i=0,lefmost=-1. leftmost keeps track of the position of last index of last chosen set.
int solve(int i, int leftmost)
{
    if (i >= numberOfTerms)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (solvedValues[i] != -1)
    {
        return solvedValues[i];
    }

    if (leftMosts[i] <= leftmost)
    {
        return solve(i+1, leftmost);// we cant go choose leftMosts[i] to rightMosts[i] so we move on
    }

    // decide if it is better to choose current leftMosts[i] to rightMosts[i] or better to simply move on and skip this.
    return solvedValues[i] = std::max(comf(leftMosts[i], rightMosts[i]) + solve(rightMosts[i]+1, rightMosts[i]), solve(i+1, leftmost));
}

void init()
{
    scanf("%d", &numberOfTerms);
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTerms; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &terms[i]);
    }
    // init all as -1
    memset(solvedValues, -1, sizeof(solvedValues));
    memset(leftMosts, -1, sizeof(leftMosts));
    memset(rightMosts, -1, sizeof(rightMosts));
}

int main()
{
    init();

    // calc leftMosts[i] and rightMosts[i] for all 'i in terms
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTerms; i++)
    {
        for (int leftIndex = 0; leftIndex < i; leftIndex++)
        {
            if (terms[leftIndex] == terms[i])
            {
                leftMosts[i] = leftIndex;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int rightIndex = numberOfTerms-1; rightIndex > i; rightIndex--)
        {
            if (terms[rightIndex] == terms[i])
            {
                rightMosts[i] = rightIndex;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (leftMosts[i] == -1)
        {
            leftMosts[i] = i;// if there is no leftmost occ, then leftmost is current
        }

        if (rightMosts[i] == -1)
        {
            rightMosts[i] = i;// same as above for rightmost
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", solve(0, -1));

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the test case:

> 100 931 4584 2116 3004 3813 62 2819 2998 2080 4906 3198 2443 2952 3793 1958 3864 3985 3169 3134 4011 4525 995 4163 308 4362 1148 4906 3092 
>   1647 244 1370 1424 2753 84 2997 1197 2606 425 3501 2606 683 4747 3884 4787 2166 3017 3080 4303 3352 1667 2636 3994 757 2388 870 1788 988 
>   1303 0 1230 1455 4213 2113 2908 871 1997 3878 4604 1575 3385 236 847 2524 3937 1803 2678 4619 1125 3108 1456 3017 1532 3845 3293 2355
>   2230 4282 2586 2892 4506 3132 4570 1872 2339 2166 3467 3080 2693 1925 2308

The Correct Output Should Be :

> 227685

The Wrong Output on Codeforces :

> 245849

Again, on my machine the code works fine and outputs 227685 but when it is run online, the code outputs 245849 for some reason.
The code can be [tested online here.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php)
And here's an [image of the code working on a local machine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1RWs.jpg)

I would love to understand what is causing this.

**Update :**
This error was caused as the variable `leftmost` in the function `solve(int i,int leftmost)` was not taken into account when the final calculated value was set to `solvedValues[i]`. This is a bad/incorrect approach to the problem and results in problems such as the order in `std::max()` affecting the output of the code.

Comment: you probably have some undefined behavior. If you can try running the code under valgrind. It will find many of those things

Comment: Is part of the competition having unintelligible names?

Comment: @Caleth, sorry for that. Generally competitive programmers have to focus on getting the task done asap without focusing on code readability. In fact, I just added the comments in the code for this question so that it may be easier to understand. I will update the code soon and change the variable names so that it is better for everyone.

Comment: Just updated the code and added more comments explaining the use of every variable.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of `leftmost` in `slv`?

Comment: Most of your comments repeat *what the code does*. They need to say *why the code does what it does*

Comment: @Caleth, 'leftmost' keeps track of the last index that is part of a group. So if the array has 5 elements, and we have chosen the first 2 as a group, then leftmost is equal to 2. Thus, leftmost in a way tells us that we can only form groups in the array remaining from leftmost till n, as we have already used indices till index 'leftmost'.

Comment: Your code would be easier to manage and more efficient if you used an array of structures, rather than parallel arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Reason for the different result**

The parameters you use in `std::max` are being executed in a different order online and on your local machine. When `comf(leftMosts[i], rightMosts[i]) + solve(rightMosts[i]+1, rightMosts[i])` is executed before `solve(i+1, leftmost)`, you get the desired result. If the order is swapped, you get the wrong result.

**Refactored code that works**

Here's your code that I refactored for better readability. One of the things I did was breaking up the long return statement in `slv`. If you switch the order of the lines `int a =...` and `int b =...` you will get the wrong result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

// terms[] stores the value of all the terms. leftMosts[i] and rightMosts[i] store the leftmost and rightmost occurrences of the ith element in terms[]. 
//solvedValues[] stands for dynamic programming and stores the pre calculated terms of the function solve()
int numberOfTerms;
int terms[5005];
int leftMosts[5005];
int rightMosts[5005];
int solvedValues[5005];

int comf(int left,int right)
{ 
    std::set<int> track;
    int ret = 0;
    for(int i = left; i <= right; i++)
    {
        if (!track.count(terms[i]))
        {
            ret = (ret^terms[i]);
            track.insert(terms[i]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

// below, solve stands for 'solve', it is terms recursive memoized function
// returns max sequence from i to (numberOfTerms-1). to find max, call solve(0, -1) so i=0,lefmost=-1. leftmost keeps track of the position of last index of last chosen set.
int solve(int i, int leftmost)
{
    if (i >= numberOfTerms)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (solvedValues[i] != -1)
    {
        return solvedValues[i];
    }

    if (leftMosts[i] <= leftmost)
    {
        return solve(i+1, leftmost);// we cant go choose leftMosts[i] to rightMosts[i] so we move on
    }

    // decide if it is better to choose current leftMosts[i] to rightMosts[i] or better to simply move on and skip this.
    int a = comf(leftMosts[i], rightMosts[i]) + solve(rightMosts[i]+1, rightMosts[i]);
    int b = solve(i+1, leftmost);
    return solvedValues[i] = std::max(a, b);
}

void init()
{
    scanf("%d", &numberOfTerms);
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTerms; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &terms[i]);
    }
    // init all as -1
    memset(solvedValues, -1, sizeof(solvedValues));
    memset(leftMosts, -1, sizeof(leftMosts));
    memset(rightMosts, -1, sizeof(rightMosts));
}

int main()
{
    init();

    // calc leftMosts[i] and rightMosts[i] for all 'i in terms
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTerms; i++)
    {
        for (int leftIndex = 0; leftIndex < i; leftIndex++)
        {
            if (terms[leftIndex] == terms[i])
            {
                leftMosts[i] = leftIndex;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int rightIndex = numberOfTerms-1; rightIndex > i; rightIndex--)
        {
            if (terms[rightIndex] == terms[i])
            {
                rightMosts[i] = rightIndex;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (leftMosts[i] == -1)
        {
            leftMosts[i] = i;// if there is no leftmost occ, then leftmost is current
        }

        if (rightMosts[i] == -1)
        {
            rightMosts[i] = i;// same as above for rightmost
        }
    }

    printf("%d numberOfTerms", solve(0, -1));

    return 0;
}
```

**What do we learn from this?**

Readable, clean code is not only nice to your fellow programmers (and yourself), it also reduces the risk of bugs.

Comment: It's impossible for any implementation of `std::max` to evaluate its arguments twice. It would be possible for a macro, but it can't be one.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You are right, that explanation was wrong. It's the order of the statements. I have updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @MaxVollmer, Thanks! I don't think I would have figured this out alone.